# What is the confidence for rule for $\emptyset \implies A $?

Tags: self-study, data-mining, association-rules

I'm looking at a question for association rule mining and this comes up:

- What is the confidence for $\emptyset \implies A $?
- What is the confidence for $ A \implies \emptyset $?

Given: 
$$\newcommand{\Conf}{{\rm Conf}}\newcommand{\Support}{{\rm Support}}\Conf(A \implies B) = \frac {\Support(A \cup B)} {\Support(A)}$$

Therefore,
$$\Conf(\emptyset \implies A) = \frac {\Support(A \cup \emptyset)} {\Support(\emptyset)} = \frac {\Support(A)} {\Support(\emptyset)}$$

Similarly,

$$\Conf(A\implies \emptyset) = \frac {\Support(A \cup \emptyset)} {\Support(A)} = \frac {\Support(A)} {\Support(A)} = 100\%$$

However, it doesn't sound right to me.

I would really appreciate any pointers.

Comment: Is this a question from a course or textbook? If so, please add the `[self-study]`
tag & read its [wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: it is. but from a past exam. we have a few different answers but none makes much sense to all of us. I was hoping someone could give us a hint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you say it doesn't sound right to you?

Your current answer is perfectly correct : $$Conf(\emptyset \Rightarrow A) = \frac{Support(A)}{Support(\emptyset)} = Support(A)$$ and $$Conf(A \Rightarrow \emptyset) = 1$$.

Comment: why would $\Support(\emptyset) = 1$? that's one of the things I don't understand

Comment: That is because $\emptyset$ is included in any itemset : it is thus present in all the transactions